# Can I use this name since it is the same?

Tags: translation, kanji, english-to-japanese, names, japanese-to-english

My name is Annaka. There is a city in Japan called 安中　(Annaka) spelled and sounds the exact same way. Can I use “安中” to refer to myself? If not, what variation could I use?

Comment: It's your choice but I have a feeling your name sounds more like アナカ than アンナカ to a Japanese ear.

Answer (score 1):

That's a nice name.

> Can I use “安中” to refer to myself?

Depends on what you mean by "can I"

- Can I write "from 安中" when writing casual letters to friends?

Yes, your choice, just as aguijonazo commented.

- Can I write 安中 on official documentation and registration?

You better comply to the formatting on your [registration papers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C5%ABminhy%C5%8D) - if it's written in alphabet, you better use alphabet.

- Is it a safe set of kanjis to be used as names as a Japanese citizen?

Yes, that combination is not vulgar.

- Is it a good set of kanjis?

There's an entire business regarding names, so you better ask the "experts". Sorry I couldn't find a good English explanation but here's a [Japanese Wiki page](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A7%93%E5%90%8D%E5%88%A4%E6%96%AD) . It's one of those spiritual things but many parents and companies utilize such services even today.

---

> If not, what variation could I use?

It depends on why not. Without making assumptions, here's my opinion on your name:

安中 is not weird, it's a reasonable combination of kanji. But I've never heard of that city, and my first guess would be Yasunaka and then people would correct me. Such interaction happens all the time, so I guess it's part of the culture.

**If あんなか アンナカ**

When I hear An or Ann, the first kanji I imagine is 杏 . Naka can be 中 or 仲 . They both have meanings - 中 is middle or center while 仲 is bond or friendship. 安中, 安仲, 杏中, 杏仲 all are acceptable for me. You can also experiment with three kanjis like 杏奈華 . It's not strange too, but not as common as the two kanji suggestions.

**If あなか アナカ**

亜中 or 亜仲 .